# CSS code not working the way It should in the WordPress header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want the size of the button to be shorter like the following image:

[image: Reference Image]

But when I added the custom CSS to the WordPress site, It changed the button size.

```
#menu-item-11695 {
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:9px 8px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
#menu-item-11695:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background-color:#72b352;
}
#menu-item-11695:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

---

[image: Result]

Comment: looks like you want margin on your button, not padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inspect the parent of your buttons. Your button probably takes 100% height from his parent.

Comment: Thanks for your help, any idea how where can I get the parent code and change 100% height?

Comment: inspect the parent with chrome dev tools and show us the rendered code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#menu-item-11695 {
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff !important;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:9px 8px !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
```

you can add "!important" just before the semicolon and Wordpress will ignore the other style and apply those styles instead. But you should be very precise on the selector.

Comment: This is a bad way to code as it takes your styling out of the cascading style of the sheet. Just add the parent classes or elements before your defined ID as it will give it more weighting and therefore have it's styling used.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added the !important but still it did not work.